# How to solve problems with the float type of a column in sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table (name: table_example) in a database on postgres:

```
      id     number_sensor       
     0001          1              
     0002          2              
     0003          8              
     0004          4              
     0005          1
```

I need to create a new column that receives the result of a calculation using the column "number_Sensor". So, I created a new column, named "results" in the table. Defined as the float type.

```
        ALTER TABLE table_example
        ADD result float(10)
```

The addition of the new column was done perfectly. As below:

```
      id     number_sensor       result
     0001          1              [null]
     0002          2              [null]
     0003          8              [null]
     0004          4              [null]
     0005          1              [null]
```

However, when I do the necessary calculation:

```
        UPDATE table_example
        SET result = (number_sensor / 4)
```

I get the following values ​​in the "result" column:

```
       id     number_sensor       result
     0001          1              0
     0002          2              0
     0003          8              2
     0004          4              1
     0005          1              0
```

However, I would like the output to be as follows:

```
      id     number_sensor       result
     0001          1              0.25
     0002          2              0.50
     0003          8              2
     0004          4              1
     0005          1              0.25
```

Comment: You should understand that 1) "integers" and "floating point" are two different "kinds" of numbers, 2) "integer arithmetic" (e.g. `1/ 4`) will always TRUNCATE to "integer values".  3) The solution is to use FLOATING POINT ARITHMETIC, e.g. `1.0/4.0`.  Here's a good article: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres does integer division.  Just throw in a decimal place:

```
UPDATE table_example
    SET result = (number_sensor / 4.0);
```

Or convert to a `float` if you prefer that method:

```
UPDATE table_example
    SET result = (number_sensor::float / 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you do *not* persist that column. Rather, calculate it whenever you query the table:

```
SELECT id, number_sensor,
       number_sensor / 4.o  -- avoid integer division
FROM table_example;
```

If you need that often, create a view for that query.